# unlock Locked java files Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Can some tell me why i am not able to edit some java files in android studio(2.2.2) and why i am seeing a lock at the java files. How to make it editable.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFJYC.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is a part of any library i think you should not unlock it.
But it is a class created by you then you can unlock it .

At right corner below of your logcat you can see a lock like this :

[image: Locked class symbol]

you can achieve this by clicking the lock then it will unlock the class

Comment: How can I unlock it if it is a part of library? @Sushrita